# Handling alert in Protractor

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing, angular-e2e

I have a simple case of handling an alert with Protractor which I could not solve. I simply want to navigate to another application page after accepting the alert. I've tried the following cases which did not succeed:
(PS, if I comment out the failing tests all other tests run as expected)
(PS2, the alert is activate via a `@HostListener('window:beforeunload')` annotation)

1)

```
const alert = await browser.get('/homepage')
  .catch(function () {
    return browser.switchTo().alert();
});
await alert.accept();
await browser.get('/homepage');
const url = await browser.getCurrentUrl();
expect(url).endsWith('/homepage');
```

2. 

```
await browser.get('/homepage').catch(function () {
  return browser.switchTo().alert().then(function (alert) {
    alert.accept();
  });
});
await browser.get('/homepage');
const url = await browser.getCurrentUrl();
expect(url).endsWith('/homepage');
```

In this cases, the browser navigates to `data:text/html,<html></html>` and I get an error like: `Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:52132`

3)

```
await browser.get('/homepage');
await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent(), 10000);
await browser.switchTo().alert().accept();
await browser.get('/homepage');
const url = await browser.getCurrentUrl();
expect(url).endsWith('/homepage');
```

In this case I get an error like: `UnexpectedAlertOpenError: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : }`

4)

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
await browser.get('/homepage');
await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent(), 10000);
await browser.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

In this case, the browser navigates to the homepage. But, subsequent tests fail with the error: `Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:60759`

I also tried to revert the `ignoreSynchronization` to `false` at the end of the test but it did not make a difference.

I run the tests by something like: `npm run e2e -- --baseUrl=http://localhost:9001`

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a list of problems

1. `ignoreSynchronization` has no effect since protractor v5, use `browser.waitForAngularEnabled` instead
2. <s>Re: `UnexpectedAlertOpenError: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : }` All of sudden I started getting that error today too, and I recently updated my chrome and the driver to the latest version. So I suppose it's related. No solution so far though, but problems like this sometimes resolved within the next chromedriver update</s>
3. your #3 should be the working code, <s>but because of what I mentioned in my #2 it doesn't work. Try to check it you can update your chromedriver, and please let me know if helps. I'll update mine too</s>

P.S.

Just checked my code, not related to chromedriver. the solution is this function below

```
/**
* accept alert popup if present
*/
async acceptAlertPopup() {
    if (await ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent()())
        await browser
            .switchTo()
            .alert()
            .accept();
}
```

Comment: No chance... I'm getting: `UnexpectedAlertOpenError: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : }`

The test is something like this now. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong:

`it('should show alert when passwords do not match', async () => {
   ....
    const displayed = await passwordResetFinishComponent.alertDangerElement.isDisplayed();
    expect(displayed).to.eq(true); // runs fine till here
    await browser.get('/homepage');
    if (await ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent())
      await browser
        .switchTo()
        .alert()
        .accept();
  });`